# how to load unstructured non-queryset data with django-tables2

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'd like to use django-tables2 to display data from a spreadsheet or csv file. The data will always be dynamic so I need a way of  dynamically adding columns to my django-tables2 table. From the documentation there seems to be no way of doing this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, you can use type to [construct classes dynamically](http://jfine-python-classes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/type-name-bases-dict.html#type-name-bases-dict).

Let's use the example from [the docs](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/table-data.html), which defines a table with one column, `name`.

```
import django_tables2 as tables

data = [
    {"name": "Bradley"},
    {"name": "Stevie"},
]

class NameTable(tables.Table):
    name = tables.Column()
```

This could be defined dynamically with

```
NameTable = type('NameTable', (tables.Table,), {'name': tables.Column()})
```

The data in your spreadsheet will be more complicated, but the same approach should work.

Comment: This solution worked for me. i did not know type could do this.