# django-tables2: Adding columns/fields dynamically

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I want to add a new field when somebody checks an option in my web page ("Add column 'external id' ")

```
table = IssueTable(issue_list)
show_ext = request.GET.get('show_ext', 0)
if show_ext:
    table._meta.fields = table._meta.fields + ('external_id',)
```

I thought doing that it was the solution but I didn't succeed. The external_id is part of the model. table._meta.fields doesnt get updated and of course I cannot see the column in the table when this one is rendered.

```
class IssueTable(tables.Table):

    def render_id(self, value, record):
        if record.status.upper() in ['RESOLVED', 'INVALID']:
            return mark_safe('<a href="%s"><s>#%s</s></a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(record.pk,)), record.pk))
        else:
            return mark_safe('<a href="%s">#%s</a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(record.pk,)), record.pk))

    def render_title(self, value, record):
        return mark_safe('<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse('issues.views.view', args=(record.id,)), value))

    class Meta(object):
        model = Issue
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'product', 'type', 'priority', 'status', 'created')
        attrs = {'class': 'table table-bordered'}
        empty_text = _('No records found')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, but you could generate the list of fields based on `show_ext`, then [generate the table class dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31856958/how-to-load-unstructured-non-queryset-data-with-django-tables2/31862383#31862383). I'm not sure how to add fields once the table has been initialized, or whether it is even possible.

Comment: @Alasdair yeah, that's the idea! to generate that field/column after the table is created.